# Laravel custom facade class 'name' does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my controller I have:

```
use App\Facade\Social;

$twitter_id = $entity->twitter_business;

if (!empty($twitter_id)) {
    $twitter_array = Social::twitter($twitter_id, $id);
    $postCount = $postCount + count($twitter_array);
    Log::info('Twitter ok for', ['entity_id' => $id]);
}
```

Facade itself:

```
protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
{
    return 'social';
}
```

and service provider:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('social', function ($app) {
        return new Social();
    });
}
```

However I get an error:

> Class social does not exist

Provider and facade are both included in config/app.php so why does this error occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to clear cache:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

And autoload new providers:

```
composer dump-autoload
```